# Using cv2.VideoCapture() inside a function OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI-based face recognition program with tkinter and opencv. I have used the function cv2.VideoCapture() before, but usually NOT inside a function and it worked successfully.

This time, though, I wanted to use it inside a function, but the program just does not run. I got no errors in the terminal, and the window just froze.

Here is my code (I haven't yet added the face recognition functionality)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='#3d3d3d')
f1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, bg='#3d3d3d')
f1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.53, anchor=tk.CENTER)
feed = tk.Label(f1)
feed.pack()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def capture():    
    while cap.isOpened():
        img = cap.read()[1]  
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # changing color to RGB
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img1)) 
        feed['image'] = img  # putting the webcam feed in the 'feed' LabelFrame

capture()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to input values 0, 1, -1 for the VideoCapture() function, but the problem persisted

Note that this is not my full code and I have just included the important parts. I am asking this question because I want to implement this functionality on a Toplevel() window which is opened by clicking a button. The code for the Toplevel() window is indside a function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Another issue is that you used while loop which will block `root.mainloop()` from executing.

Comment: I had checked that link earlier, and it doesnt fix the issue

Comment: The problem, as far as I have tested it, lies within the VideoCapture() function rather than tkinter

Comment: infact the `feed['image'] = img` line is performing that same function which was provided as an answer for the link you sent

Comment: No `feed['image']` is used to change the *`image` option* of the label, whereas `feed.image = img` is using *an attribute named "image"* to store the reference of the image.  As I said, `root.mainloop()` has been blocked from executing due to the while loop, so you cannot see the window at all.

Comment: I see, ok mate, can you suggest some fixes if possible? I got your point though

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two issues in your code:

- using while loop which will block `root.mainloop()` from executing.  Use `after()` instead.
- image created inside a function will be garbage collected if its reference is not saved

Below is a modified code to fix the above issues:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='#3d3d3d')
root.geometry('800x600')

f1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, bg='#3d3d3d')
f1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.53, anchor=tk.CENTER)

feed = tk.Label(f1)
feed.pack()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# used after() instead of while loop
def capture():
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, img = cap.read()
        if ret:
            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
            img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # changing color to RGB
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img1))
            feed['image'] = img  # putting the webcam feed in the 'feed' LabelFrame
            feed.image = img # save reference of the image
    root.after(10, capture)

capture()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "[...] *inside a function* will be GC'd" is misleading. if you mean to say that `feed['image'] = img` only causes a **weak** reference, say so ("inside a function" would be a misleading explanation). I don't know if it does or not.

Comment: @Christoph I have a if condition, not always.

Comment: you missed my point

Comment: hey! your solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot